# How parse complex json with property d

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, json.net

i have problem in deserialize JSON using C# in windows phone 8 please help me to do it:-

This the JSON result i have:-

> {"d":"{\"TickTime\":\"29/04/2014 19:13:41\",\"Symbols\":[{\"I\":61,\"H\":0.8551,\"L\":0.8516,\"A\":0.855,\"B\":0.8545},{\"I\":62,\"H\":1301.4,\"L\":1286.3,\"A\":1296.6,\"B\":1296.4}]}"}

This is class i use:-

```
public class OuterRootObject
{
public string d { get; set; }
}


public class RootObject
{

public DateTime TickTime { get; set; }
public List<Symbols> Symbols{ get; set; }
 }

public class Result
{
public int I { get; set; }
public double A { get; set; }
public double B { get; set; }
public double H { get; set; }
public double L{ get; set;
}
```

i have used this code to deserlized this JSON but its not working because inside outer root result is Time Value and Symbols array and i have no idea how to parse them at the same time.

```
var outerRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterRootObject>(My JSON);
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(outerRoot.d);
```

Comment: What does the `Symbols` class look like?

Comment: Its list of array :( its complex i don't know how to desirilize it

Comment: I'm reopening due to your edit an hour ago. That does attempt to provide information on what you tried and why you think it's not working. Someone may be able to answer it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working 100% just change the

```
public DateTime TickTime { get; set; }
```

to

```
public string TickTime { get; set; }
```

Then use this to Deserialize your JSON

```
var outerRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterRootObject>(your JSON);
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(outerRoot.d);



                             foreach (var SymbolsInfo in root.Symbols)
                             {
                                 var i = SymbolsInfo .I;
                                 var a = SymbolsInfo .A;
                                 var b = SymbolsInfo .B;
                                 var l = SymbolsInfo .L;
                                 var h = SymbolsInfo .H;
                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your code to work with two changes.

1. I changed the `Symbols` property to hold a `List<Result>` instead of a `List<Symbols>`, since you did not define a `Symbols` class that I can see, and the `Result` class seems to match the JSON.
2. I used an `IsoDateTimeConverter` with a custom date format to handle the `TickTime` since the date in the JSON does not conform to the standard ISO 8601 datetime format that Json.Net expects.

Here is the full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{""d"": ""{\""TickTime\"":\""29/04/2014 19:13:41\"",\""Symbols\"":[{\""I\"":61,\""H\"":0.8551,\""L\"":0.8516,\""A\"":0.855,\""B\"":0.8545},{\""I\"":62,\""H\"":1301.4,\""L\"":1286.3,\""A\"":1296.6,\""B\"":1296.4}]}""}";

        IsoDateTimeConverter dateConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        };

        var outerRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterRootObject>(json);
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(outerRoot.d, dateConverter);

        Console.WriteLine("TickTime: " + root.TickTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
        foreach (Result r in root.Symbols)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I: " + r.I);
            Console.WriteLine("A: " + r.A);
            Console.WriteLine("B: " + r.B);
            Console.WriteLine("H: " + r.H);
            Console.WriteLine("L: " + r.L);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

public class OuterRootObject
{
    public string d { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public DateTime TickTime { get; set; }
    public List<Result> Symbols { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public double H { get; set; }
    public double L { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
TickTime: 29-Apr-2014 07:13:41 PM
I: 61
A: 0.855
B: 0.8545
H: 0.8551
L: 0.8516

I: 62
A: 1296.6
B: 1296.4
H: 1301.4
L: 1286.3
```